# How to add struct to an array of structs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Ok I have a struct defined as such...

```
typedef struct
{
    enum COMMAND command;
    enum CMD_SOURCE source;
    CHAR parameters[16];
} focuserCommand;
```

I am trying to make a function that will add an instance of this type of struct to an array of focuserCommands. The array is defined like this...

```
extern focuserCommand CommandBuffer[CMD_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

the function I am trying to write should take a pointer to a `focuserCommand` and add it to `CommandBuffer`. I am implementing CommandBuffer as a FIFO ring buffer so I know i need to move the tail forwared so that my other functions can see that the buffer contains data. CmdBuffHead and CmdBuffTail represent the read and write pointers of the buffer. Writes are added to the tail, reads are made from the head.

```
void AddCmdToBfr( focuserCommand * cmd )
{
// What goes here to add the struct pointed to by cmd to 
    //   element CmdBuffTail of the buffer?

    CmdBuffTail++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have the variable `CmdBuffTail` pointing at the next element of `CommandBuffer` to be written to, then:

```
void AddCmdToBfr(focusCommand *cmd)
{
    assert(CmdBuffTail >= 0 && CmdBuffTail < CMD_BUFFER_SIZE);
    CommandBuffer[CmdBuffTail++] = *cmd;
    if (CmdBuffTail >= CMD_BUFFER_SIZE)
        CmdBuffTail = 0;
}
```

This preserves the invariant that you need - that the index is in the range 0..CMD_BUFFER_SIZE-1.

You may also need a separate index (`CmdBuffHead` perhaps) to identify where to read from.  If so, you would probably need to alter that value in `AddCmdToBfr()` if `CmdBuffTail` if catches up with it.

---

After fixing a goof copying the incoming command, it occurs to me that you need to think carefully about the memory management.  In this case, your `focususerCommand` structure is simple enough (unless the typedef `CHAR` hides a pointer - in which case, slap wrists; don't hide pointers) that you can simply copy it with impunity.  If you can't copy the structure simply (because it contains pointers to allocated memory), then you need to ensure you understand who owns the data to make sure that (a) any allocated memory *is* released, and (b) any allocated memory is released just *once*.  This would mean, for example, that instead of just copying the new command over the old, you would have to first release the memory allocated to the old entry.  Think in terms of C++ copy constructors and destructors - in C.

Comment: i tried this but I get a compiler error at the line `CommandBuffer[CmdBuffTail++] = cmd;` saying incompatible types in assignment. Is it because cmd is a pointer to a struct and not the struct itself?

Comment: @Jordan: my mistake - I forgot to dereference (copy) the `cmd` variable; I fixed it to `CommandBuffer[CmdBuffTail] = *cmd;`.  Apologies.